# Validating Edit Text which is present in Alert Dialog in Android

Tags: database, validation, android-edittext

I'm having an Alert Dialog in my Activity and it consists of 3 edit text fields in it,I'm taking the user input like name,phone number,email.Now i want to validate the fields weather they are null or not..?I have tried many code snippets which was found in Google but none works fine.
What i need is user should enter the details in the edit text fields and click on submit from alert dialog box then those values should be inserted into the database.it should check weather user entered a null value or not..?and display a toast or error message.Please help me in solving this

Here is my code

```
        AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            ll1=new LinearLayout(this);
            ll1.setOrientation(1);
            final EditText name= new EditText(this);
            final EditText phno= new EditText(this);
            final EditText email= new EditText(this);
            ll1.addView(name);
            ll1.addView(phno);
            ll1.addView(email);
            name.setHint("UserName");
            phno.setHint("Mobile No");
            email.setHint("Email-id");
            adb.setTitle("Registration");
            adb.setView(ll1);

            adb.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        String nme=name.getText().toString().trim();
                        String phn=phno.getText().toString().trim();
                        String mail=email.getText().toString().trim();


                        if(nme==""||phn==""||mail==""){

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Enter All Feilds" ,5000).show();
                         }
                        else
                         db.execSQL("insert into user_reg values('"+nme+"','"+phn+"','"+mail+"')");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered Successfully",5000).show();
                        displayData();*/
                }
            }); 

                adb.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                adb.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace '==' with '.equals()'
'==' is a reference comparison..it just compares 2 objects, it checks to see if the objects refer to the same place in memory.
'.equals' compares the contents of the 2 objects.

```
if(nme.equals("") || phn.equals("") || mail.equals("")){

                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please Enter All Feilds",
                            5000).show();
                }
```

else check with

```
nme.length() == 0
```